# Can clock edge events be synthesized inside always blocks in verilog?

Tags: events, verilog, hdl, synthesis

I have two clocks, clk0 and clk1. I want a counter to count on posedge of clk0 but reset at posedge of clk1. The important thing to note is that the reset should occur only on the posedge and not when clk1 is high. So the below code is not possible.

```
always @(posedge clk0 or posedge clk1)
begin
     if (clk1)
              count <= 0;
     else
              count <= count + 1;
end
```

We cannot drive the counter from two always blocks as well. So the below is not possible:

```
always @ (posedge clk0)
begin
     count <= count + 1;
end

always @ (posedge clk1)
begin
     count <= 0;
end
```

So my question: What offers a similar functionality like

```
always @(posedge clk0 or posedge clk1)
begin
     if (posedge clk1)
              count <= 0;
     else
              count <= count + 1;
end
```

And is synthesizable?

I want a counter which counts on posedge of clk0 and resets on posedge of clk1. clk0 is faster than clk1 by an order of magnitude. The design needs to be synthesizable.

Comment: No! Think about it this way: If that should be translated into hardware, what should that hardware look like? AFAIK no such component exist.

Comment: @Oldfart I realize that having posedge clk1 within the always block is invalid syntax. But I need that functionality. If clk0 has higher frequency than clk1, the counter does not increment as long as clk1 is high, effectively 'wasting' clk0 cycles. Is there a work around?

Comment: Please specify in detail what you want to achieve: 'I have two clocks and a counter and I want....'. Note that using two unrelated clocks may create situations which can not be solved.

Comment: @Oldfart I want a counter which counts on posedge of clk0 and resets on posedge of clk1. clk0 is faster than clk1 by an order of magnitude. The design needs to be synthesizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to transfer the 'event' from clk1 to clk0. This is a clock domain crossing issue and thus requires synchronization.

```
reg clk1_meta,clk1_sync,clk1_prev;
always @(posedge clk0 or negedge reset_n) // async low reset as example
begin
   if (!reset_n)
   begin
      clk1_meta <= 1'b0; 
      clk1_sync <= 1'b0; 
      clk1_prev <= 1'b0;
      counter   <= 'b0;       
   end
   else
   begin
      // transfer clk1 to clk0
      clk1_meta <= clk1;
      clk1_sync <= clk1_meta;

      // Now we have a safe signal: clk1_sync          
      clk1_prev <= clk1_sync;
      // A rising edge is when clk1_sync1 is high but previously it was low
      if (clk1_sync==1'b1 && clk1_prev==1'b0)
         counter <= 'b0;
      else
         counter <= counter + 1;
   end
end
```

There is an unavoidable delay of ~2 clk0 clock cycles before the clk1 arrives in the clk0 domain because of the synchronisation.

Comment: Yes. This is perfect! The crux of the solution is to register the value of clk1 for two edges of clk0, and then when they are unequal you reset it. Thanks!